# I have logic errors- not displaying proper results, or using default values if user inputs bad data

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program that includes a driver sundae program and a sundae class. I get no errors on compilation.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

            public class SundaeDriver
            {
                public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                    Sundae newSundae = new Sundae();
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Which sundae flavor would you like? ");
                    newSundae.setFlavor(input.nextLine());

                    if ((newSundae.getFlavor().equalsIgnoreCase("vanilla"))||
                        (newSundae.getFlavor().equalsIgnoreCase("peanut butter"))||
                        (newSundae.getFlavor().equalsIgnoreCase("chocolate"))||
                        (newSundae.getFlavor().equalsIgnoreCase("cocoanut"))||
                        (newSundae.getFlavor().equalsIgnoreCase("cookie dough"))||
                        (newSundae.getFlavor().equalsIgnoreCase("coffee"))||
                        (newSundae.getFlavor().equalsIgnoreCase("strawberry"))||
                        (newSundae.getFlavor().equalsIgnoreCase("butter pecan")))
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newSundae.setDefault();
                            newSundae.Print();
                        }

                    System.out.println("How many scoops?");
                    newSundae.setNumberOfScoops(input.nextInt());
                    if ((newSundae.getNumberOfScoops()==1)||
                        (newSundae.getNumberOfScoops()==2)||
                            (newSundae.getNumberOfScoops()==3)||
                                (newSundae.getNumberOfScoops()==4)||
                                    (newSundae.getNumberOfScoops()==5)||
                                        (newSundae.getNumberOfScoops()==6))
                    { 
                    }
                                    else
                                    {
            newSundae.setDefault();
            newSundae.Print();
            }
                        System.out.println("How many free toppings would you like");
                        int num = input.nextInt();
                        input.nextLine();
                        for (int i = 0; i<num;i++)
                        {
                        System.out.println("what free toppings would you like?");
                        String temp=input.nextLine();
                        if ((temp.equalsIgnoreCase("whipped cream"))||
                            (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("hot fudge syrup"))||
                            (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("multi colored sprinkles"))||
                            (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("cherry")))
                        {
                            newSundae.setStdTopping(temp);

                            }
                            else    
                            {
                        newSundae.setDefault();
                        newSundae.Print();
                        }
                   }
                  System.out.println("What free syrup would you like?");
                    newSundae.setFreeSyrupChoice(input.nextLine());
                    if ((newSundae.getFreeSyrupChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("hot fudge"))||
                        (newSundae.getFreeSyrupChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("chocolate"))||
                            (newSundae.getFreeSyrupChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("caramel"))||
                                (newSundae.getFreeSyrupChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("strawberry")))
                                {
                                }
                                else
                            {
                                newSundae.setDefault();
                                newSundae.Print();
                            }

                            System.out.println("How many deluxe toppings would you like?");
                            num = input.nextInt();
                            input.nextLine();
                            for (int i = 0; i<num; i++)
                            {

                                System.out.println("what extra toppings would you like");
                                String deluxe=input.nextLine();
                                if ((deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("M&Ms"))||
                                    (deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("crushed oreos"))||
                                    (deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("reeses peices"))||
                                    (deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("bwonie crunches"))||
                                    (deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("mint chocolate chip"))||
                                    (deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("marshmallows"))||
                                    (deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("peanuts"))||
                                    (deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("walnuts"))||
                                    (deluxe.equalsIgnoreCase("peanuts and walnuts")))
                                        {
                                            newSundae.setDeluxTopping(deluxe);
                                }


                                else
                                {
                                    newSundae.setDefault();
                                    newSundae.Print();
                                }
                            }

}
}
```

When the user inputs the correct Sundae flavor, type and number of free toppings and regular toppings,  the program is supposed to display the total price at the end. However, The program just ends when the user puts in all the data.

```
                public class Sundae
            {
                private String flavor;
                private int numberOfScoops;
                private double costForScoops;
                private String [] stdToppingList=new String [4];
                private String freeSyrupChoice;
                private String [] deluxeToppingList= new String [9];
                private int counterD= 0;
                private double costOfDeluxeToppings;
                private double costOfSundae;
                private final double SALES_TAX= .08625;
                private double tax;
                private final double COST_PER_DELUXE_TOPPING =.75;
                private int counterFree=0;

                public Sundae()
                {
                    flavor= " vanilla ";
                    numberOfScoops=2;
                    costForScoops=2.79;
                    stdToppingList[0]=" whipped cream ";
                    stdToppingList[1]=" hot fudge syrup ";
                    stdToppingList[2]=" multi colored sprinkles ";
                    stdToppingList[3]=" cherry ";
                }
            public String getFlavor()
            {
                return flavor;
            }
            public int getNumberOfScoops()
            {
                return numberOfScoops;
            }
            public double getCostForScoops()
            {
                return costForScoops;
            }
            public String [] getStdTopping()
            {
                return stdToppingList;
            }
            public String getFreeSyrupChoice()
            {
                return freeSyrupChoice;
            }
            public String [] getDeluxeTopping()
            {
                return deluxeToppingList;

            }
            public int getCounterD()
            {
                return counterD;
            }
            public double getCostDeluxeToppings()
            {
                return costOfDeluxeToppings;

            }
            public double getCostOFSundae()
            {
                return costOfSundae;
            }

            public void setFlavor( String selection )
            {
                flavor=selection;

            }
            public void setNumberOfScoops(int number)
            {
                numberOfScoops= number;

            }
            public void setCostForScoops()
            {
            costForScoops= numberOfScoops + .79;
            }
            public void setStdTopping( String toppings )
            {
                stdToppingList[counterFree] = toppings;
                counterFree++;
            }
            public void setFreeSyrupChoice( String syrup )
            {
                freeSyrupChoice= syrup;

            }
            public void setDeluxTopping (String xtraToppings)
            {
                deluxeToppingList[counterD] = xtraToppings;
                counterD++;
            }
            public void setDefault()
            {
            flavor= " vanilla ";
            numberOfScoops= 2;
            costForScoops=2.79;
            stdToppingList[0] = " whipped cream ";
            stdToppingList[1] = " hot fudge syrup ";
            stdToppingList[2] = " multi colored sprinkles ";
            stdToppingList[3] = " cherry" ;
            }
            public void Print()
            {
            System.out.println(flavor + " "+ numberOfScoops+ " " + costForScoops +
            " " + stdToppingList[0] + " " + stdToppingList[1] + stdToppingList[2] + stdToppingList[3]);
            setCostForScoops();
            costOfDeluxeToppings = COST_PER_DELUXE_TOPPING*counterD;
            costOfSundae = costOfDeluxeToppings + costForScoops;
            tax=SALES_TAX*costOfSundae;
            System.out.printf("Subtotal : $%.2f, tax: $%.2f, grand total: $%.2f " ,
                costOfSundae, tax, (costOfSundae+tax));
            }
        }
```

Whenever the user types in a string or value that is not user defined, I get a weird display message of

```
                   C:\Users\DrewS>java SundaeDriver
             Which sundae flavor would you like?
                 yes//purposly inputting value, should default to defsualt flavor vanilla at 2 scoops with all 4 free toppings. 
               vanilla  2 2.79 [Ljava.lang.String;@5c647e05
                         Subtotal : $2.79, tax: $0.24, grand total: $3.03    How many scoops?
         6
        How many free toppings would you like
          3
        what free toppings would you like?
      whipped cream
            what free toppings would you like?
       hot fudge
     vanilla  2 2.79 [Ljava.lang.String;@5c647e05//weird thing keeps printing
        Subtotal : $2.79, tax: $0.24, grand total: $3.03 what free toppings  would you l
                  ke?
       hot fudge syrup
                What free syrup would you like?
              chocolate
              How many deluxe toppings would you like?
            1
       what extra toppings would you like?
   mint chocolate chip
```

Comment: Is the user types a value not defined is logical that error. You must controle not valid input data, because you do math operations that can cause that problem

Comment: @Deckard27 There are alot of issues with the main, the class Sundea expects 4 toppings & 4 deluxe toppings, but the main allow for way more, causing some exceptions aswell. I'd suggest the op to redo his main.

Answer (score 1):

Your "problem" (its not really a problem, i'll explain) is from :

```
 public void Print()
 {
      System.out.println(flavor + " "+ numberOfScoops+ " " + costForScoops +
            " " +stdToppingList);
```

You see, when you call `println()`, java will try to call for each element its method `toString()`

`numberofScoops.toString()` works fine, since it's an integer, the method `toString()` is already **defined.**

The point is, when the method toString() **is not defined** for an object, it prints the name of the object and the adress of said object instead, for example if we take your `stdToppingList` (note that it's a **String Table**, not a string) :

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5c647e05
```

`Ljava.lang.String` is what it contains, your object is a String Table. And `@5c647e05`  is its hashcode.

For "fixing that" , you need to display all elements of your table one by one :

```
public void Print()
{
     System.out.println(flavor + " "+ numberOfScoops+ " " + costForScoops +
                " " + stdToppingList[0] + " " + stdToppingList[1] + stdToppingList[2] + stdToppingList[3]);
```

Since you always have 4 element in your stdToppingList, you can safely print them all. Or you could iterate through it if you were to save the number of toppings the user wants.

---

OK, now that we've fixed your `print()` function, let's dig in (Like i usually dig in my sundaes) the main issue, your main. Your main is unholy, going through your main is like seeing the Devil. As i'm writing thoses lines, i pray towards Linus for the Holy Salvation of my soul.

Anyway, let's start by what's wrong in your code :

- You set your whole object to Default anytime there's a mistake from the user.
- Your if-statements are poorly written. Why aren't you just giving the user the choice of what to choose instead of letting him in the blue ?
- When you ask for the number Free Topping, you doesnt check how many the user ask for.I mean, i would love asking for a 99 free toppings, and according to your program i can ... **But wait !** You said your number of free Toppings is 4 max. So yeah, it's a flaw
- All thoses 3 points above makes your code hard to read, hard to debug, and hard for the user to use;

I'd suggest you refactor your main and come back here once you've done, i'll be waiting for you.

*God that made me hungry.*

Comment: I added the 0 through 4 in the final print lines. However, I still see that wonky unwanted print statement, and my subtotal is still unable to print. any suggestions?

Comment: @KurtStenger Post again your print() function in your question, see us what you've changed

Comment: @KurtStenger Here, i gave you some advices on your main. Please read what i added and fix your main(), once you've done, ping me here, and i'll happily help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `print()` function you have

```
System.out.println(flavor + " "+ numberOfScoops+ " " + costForScoops +
        " " +stdToppingList);
```

Where `stdToppingList` is a `String[]`, not a String. Printing an array will give you that weird thing which javadocs of `Object.toString()` says is the

```
the name of the class + `@` + a hexadecimal representation of the object's hashcode
```

In order to print a primitive array in Java you either get a for loop and print each element and a space between or use something similar to `Arrays.toString(stdToppingList)`.

Comment: How woukd I go about implementing this into my code?

Comment: Try changing `stdToppingList` in the `println` to `Arrays.toString(stdToppingList)`. If that doesn't work, you remove the `stdToppingList` from the `println` and after the `println` use a for loop which traverses the array and prints each element. You might have to change the `println` to `print` for that.